# Firefox not rendering links properly in site header/footer

Tags: css, html, firefox, css-position

I've been designing and building a [portfolio site](http://mattpolicastro.com) and updated everything to be valid HTML5, but a friend just told me that all links in my header/footer are broken in Firefox.

The header and footer are position:fixed in my CSS — and I know there have historically been a lot of issues with rendering positioned elements in Firefox — but does anyone have any ideas for a quick fix?

Comment: Just to verify: the links transition to a light grey on hover, then link to the various pages? If so, that's very strange because I'm still seeing the bug on all my devices.

Comment: Will you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for footer that we can see and modify accordingly.

Comment: First time using this, so hopefully it's of help: http://jsfiddle.net/zf88Y/

Comment: Also, was playing with z-index (header and footer are currently set to negative values); could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are present but there seems to be some issue when you are setting html to position relative this is in both about.css and default.css (line 3)

Remove those properties and your hyperlinks become actionable.

```
html {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how it may alter other browsers so a quick regression across others maybe necessary...

Comment: I've double-checked on a couple of devices and browsers, and it seems to be working — I think it was an artefact of an earlier design that I forgot to scrub out.